Teens run away from home, live in abandoned place, rob house
I watched a movie probably around 2013 or so and I think it was relatively new (maybe brand new). Pretty sure we streamed it on Amazon or Netflix or something. I can't find what it was anywhere online. I think it was an indie movie. It was pretty well done I think. I feel like I remember it being somewhere in the US with a desert, or by the Salton sea or something.
I think some kids run away from home. They end up at this place where there's an abandoned type shed or house. Or maybe they purposely ran away to this place. This older more rebellious teen boy is living there. He's the crazy one. The other two kids stay there (one teen boy and one teen girl?). 
Then I think the older guy brings them to a neighborhood and they ride their bikes there. They break into a house? Then the home owner or the maid is home and they end up murdering or hurting that person. Then after they rob that house they ride away on their bikes.
At the end of the movie, one of the kids shoots the crazy older teen dead.  I think he does so to save his sister or the girl he likes?
If anyone knows what movie this is, I will be so thankful to finally figure it out. I have been trying to figure this out (not all the time ;)) for years.
